# Evaluation functors and injective model structure on diagram categories

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, ct.category-theory, homotopy-theory

If $M$ is a combinatorial model category, it's known by the experts that there is a ''natural'' model structure on diagram categories $Hom(C,M)$, which is the **projective model structure**. The fibrations and weak equivalences are defined point wise.

There is also the one called **injective model structure**, where the cofibrations and weak equivalences are defined point wise.

I would like to know if for a given a morphism $\alpha \in Arr(C)$, the evaluation at $\alpha$ can be a right Quillen functor with the **injective model structures on each side**:

$Ev_\alpha: Hom(C,M) \to M^2$

Thanks !

Edit: Here $M^2= Hom([0 \to 1], M)= Arr(M)$, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Do you really want to end up in MxM? Evaluation at a morphism in C should end up in the diagrams of the form A -> B in M. You could evaluate at source and target, but then it seems to me you might as well ask the question with evaluation at a single object of C, and then the answer should be clear. 

Comment: Yes by $M^2$ I meant the arrow category. I used the notation $M^2=Hom(2, M)$ where $2$ is the interval category (or the preorder given by the ordinal $2$). 

Comment: By the way, you can get the projective model structure with a much less restrictive hypothesis than $M$ being combinatorial. You just need $M$ to be cofibrantly generated (and $C$ to be small, of course). For the injective model structure it seems combinatorial is needed, though I have sometimes wondered if you can get away with less.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already observed, this is not always true, but I will give a more general sufficient condition, which I believe may also be necessary. The condition is that $\alpha$ is an epimorphism in $C$.

I will denote the one arrow category by $[1]$. The left adjoint to $\mathrm{ev}_\alpha : \mathcal{M}^C \to \mathcal{M}^{[1]}$ is the left Kan extension $\mathrm{Lan}_\alpha : \mathcal{M}^{[1]} \to \mathcal{M}^C$. It can be computed explicitly. If $X \in \mathcal{M}^{[1]}$ and $c \in C$, then $(\mathrm{Lan}_\alpha X)_c$ is the pushout of $C(\alpha_1, c) \times X_0 \to C(\alpha_1, c) \times X_1$ along $C(\alpha_1, c) \times X_0 \to C(\alpha_0, c) \times X_0$. If $\alpha$ is an epimorphism, then $C(\alpha_1, c) \to C(\alpha_0, c)$ is injective for all $c$ and the pushout in question is a pushout along a cofibration. It follows from the Gluing Lemma that $\mathrm{Lan}_\alpha$ preserves levelwise (acyclic) cofibration, so it is a left Quillen functor.

Comment: Your pushout is really a big coproduct under the stated condition, as the one in my answer. Then the epimorphism condition is actually precisely the condition I tacitly use; so we actually agree.

Comment: I guess so. It also seems that your counterexample should essentially work whenever $\alpha$ is not an epimorphism, so this condition is apparently necessary.

Comment: Thanks to both of you!
I'm not sure however if being an epimorphism is necessary. I'm thinking about all the results on direct (Reedy) categories, but I don't have a counterexample in mind right now. 

Answer (score 2):

In general, this is wrong. Consider for example the category with 3 objects $a,b,c$, a morphism $\alpha: a \rightarrow b$, a morphism $\tau: a \rightarrow c$ and two morphisms $\phi, \psi: b \rightarrow c$. Composition is defined in the only possible way. We can now actually compute the left adjoint of evaluation at $\alpha$. Given a $2$-diagram $X$, we obtain by computing the Kan extension that the left adjoint $L$ of evaluation is given as follows: It has $LX(a) = X(a)$, $LX(b) = X(b)$ and $LX(c)$ is the pushout of $X(b) \leftarrow X(a) \rightarrow X(b)$, where both maps are $X(\alpha)$. $LX(\phi)$ and $LX(\psi)$ are obtained by the two maps from $X(b)$ into this pushout. This pushout does not usually respect pointwise cofibrations: if $X(a) \rightarrow Y(a)$ and $X(b) \rightarrow Y(b)$ are cofibrations, the induced map on the pushouts need not be. For example, in topological spaces set $X(a) = *$, $X(b) = Y(a) = Y(b) = S^1$ with all involved maps either the identity of $S^1$ or the inclusion of a fixed basepoint into $S^1$. The map induced on the pushouts $S^1 \vee S^1 \rightarrow S^1$ is not even injective, so cannot be a cofibration.

However, if $C$ is such that there is a unique morphism between each two objects, I think the answer is yes. Explicitly, if I'm not mistaken, we can describe the left adjoint $L$ in this case as follows: Let $\phi_A: A \rightarrow B$ be an element of $M^2$.Then we have $L(c) = (\coprod_{End_C(b,c)} B) \coprod (\coprod_{f \in End_C(a,c), f \text{ does not factor over b via } \phi} A )$.

Given $g: c \rightarrow c'$ in $C$, the structure map $L(c) \rightarrow L(c')$ is given as follows: On $\coprod_{End_C(b,c)} B$, we send the $B$-summand f
corresponding to $f: b \rightarrow c$ to the $B$-summand in $L(c')$ corresponding to $g \circ f: b \rightarrow c'$ via the identity of $B$. The $A$-summand corresponding to a map $f: a \rightarrow c$ is either send via the identity of $A$ to the $A$-summand corresponding to $g \circ f$ or, if $g \circ f$ does factor over $\phi$, via the map $\phi_A$ to the $B$-summand corresponding to the map $b \rightarrow c$ over which $g \circ f$ factors. This map is indeed unique since $C$ has only one morphism from $b$ to $c$ anyway. It is then clear that $L$ preserves pointwise cofibrations.

Comment: Thanks again, that helps ! I think the type of categories you're describing correspond to either a posetal category or the indiscrete category associated to a set $S$; it's a groupoid like EG for a group G. In fact it's isomorphic to some EG.

Comment: Fabian, when you write $End_C(b,c)$ do you mean $Hom(b,c)$ ? If so, the hypothesis that there is a unique morphism between any two objects, means that $Hom(b,c)$ is just a one-element set so the coproduct reduces to one object. If C is like EG which is a groupoid, the image of C must lie in the biggest groupoid contained in $M$ (some people call it the interior of $M$). It's like a representation of G. So I don't know if your structure map $L(c) \to L(c') $ is invertible in $M$. What do you think ? 